Passing a pandas dataframe into a function to convert date to first of the month
I am able to convert a specific date column to start of the month for example changing 24-05-2024 to 01-05-24 using the following code:
df['date_sm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - MonthBegin(1)
I want a function (def) where I only need to specify the column names I want to change and then be able to apply the function to rather than doing the code for each of them. Is there a way to do this?

Yes, it should be simple enough to write a function that takes the DataFrame  (and perhaps the column name, if they aren't consistent among your DataFrames) you want to modify in as a parameter and returns that DataFrame with the desired changes. If you find yourself stuck when turning code like this into a reusable function, I find it helps to think in terms of "what information do I need to give my function in order for it to work?" (i.e., the function's arguments), and "What do I want to get out of this function?" (i.e. the return value)

if you want a function that mutates the DataFrame in place:
def col_to_monthbegin(df, col):
    df[f'{col}_sm'] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1, 'date': pd.date_range('2024-01-01', periods=5)})
col_to_monthbegin(df, 'date')

print(df)
#  A       date    date_sm
# 0  1 2024-01-01 2023-12-01
# 1  1 2024-01-02 2024-01-01
# 2  1 2024-01-03 2024-01-01
# 3  1 2024-01-04 2024-01-01
# 4  1 2024-01-05 2024-01-01

Note that the first day of the month shifted to the previous month, to avoid that you can use:
def col_to_monthbegin(df, col):
    df[f'{col}_sm'] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]) + pd.DateOffset(day=1)

# or
def col_to_monthbegin(df, col):
    df[f'{col}_sm'] = (pd.to_datetime(df[col])
                      + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
                      - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
                      )

# example

#    A       date    date_sm
# 0  1 2024-01-01 2024-01-01
# 1  1 2024-01-02 2024-01-01
# 2  1 2024-01-03 2024-01-01
# 3  1 2024-01-04 2024-01-01
# 4  1 2024-01-05 2024-01-01

variant to handle several columns:
def col_to_monthbegin(df, cols):
    tmp = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)
                                 + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
                                 - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))
    df[tmp.columns.astype(str)+'_sm'] = tmp

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1, 'date': pd.date_range('2024-01-01', periods=5),
                  'date2': pd.date_range('2025-01-01', periods=5)})
col_to_monthbegin(df, ['date', 'date2'])

print(df)

#    A       date      date2    date_sm   date2_sm
# 0  1 2024-01-01 2025-01-01 2024-01-01 2025-01-01
# 1  1 2024-01-02 2025-01-02 2024-01-01 2025-01-01
# 2  1 2024-01-03 2025-01-03 2024-01-01 2025-01-01
# 3  1 2024-01-04 2025-01-04 2024-01-01 2025-01-01
# 4  1 2024-01-05 2025-01-05 2024-01-01 2025-01-01

